Error Uploading apk to BrowserStack in Azure
I'm working with Browserstack and Azure. When It uploads apk with task BrowserStack App Uploader. Azure show the error

[BrowserStackAppUploader] Error in uploading app :
{"error":"[BROWSERSTACK_APP_UNZIP_FAILED] Invalid app: The unzip of
your app failed"

My task:
- task: BrowserStackAppUploader@0
  displayName: 'Uploading apk to BrowserStack'
  inputs:
    appPath: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/Release2.apk'

Successful Uploader App from Browserstack to Azure


Have you configured BrowserStack in Azure Pipelines? 2. Please try to use REST API to upload your app to Browserstack on your local machine. If there is the same issue, it's may be related to your app itself or Browserstack. If it works, the issue is related to the DevOps pipeline.


Hi @Pedro Payares? What's the latest state of the issue? Are you able to upload your app to BrowserStack after configuring BrowserStack in Azure Pipelines?

Testing in my pipeline, BrowserStackAppUploader@0 works fine. Below is the yaml I used.
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: BrowserStackConfig@0
  inputs:
    BrowserStackServiceEndPoint: '{BrowserStack service connection}'

- task: BrowserStackAppUploader@0
  inputs:
    appPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/app-release.apk'
    appCustomId: 'MyApp'


If it doesn't work in your pipeline. Try to upload your .apk manually or using REST API to check if there are some issues with your .apk.

Thanks, The artifact was corrupt. My task is working now
